# AdMob failed to load ad on smaller screen size

Tags: android, admob, ads

I'm having a problem with AdMob and ads in general for a few days now.

The problem is, ads load just fine on bigger screen sizes, for example, my Samsung S7 Edge loads the ad and shows it. However, on my Galaxy S3 and Galaxy S4 mini, the ad fails to load.

The output with the Ads tag:

```
14127-14127/com.example I/Ads: Starting ad request.
14127-14138/com.example W/Ads: There was a problem getting an ad response. ErrorCode: 0
14127-14127/com.example W/Ads: Failed to load ad: 0
```

My layout file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/main_rv_playlists"
        android:padding="16dp"
        android:layout_above="@+id/main_adview"
        />

    <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
        android:id="@+id/main_adview"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        ads:adSize="SMART_BANNER"
        ads:adUnitId="@string/main_banner_id"
        />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Code:

```
AdView adView = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.main_adview);
        AdRequest.Builder builder = new AdRequest.Builder();
        adView.loadAd(builder.build());
```

As you can see, I'm not using any padding with my root view, and the width of the ad view is set to match_parent, so there should be enough space. The adSize is set to SMART_BANNER. Test ads are not working as well, if I add my device as a test device, it still won't show the ad.

Interstitial ads are not working on the smaller devices as well, they're working on the bigger ones.

The ad unit itself is old, and like I said, it works on bigger screen sizes, so the ad unit itself is not the problem. And my account is not suspended or anything. In fact, I still get some revenue from the ads, but the show rate is about 65%.

I even tried using MoPub as a replacement, it still showed on my S7 edge but not on my S3.

I've tried every possible solution I could find, nothing worked.

Comment: My problem started around Jan 10, 2017.  Since then, my show rate went down from 99% to around 88% to 90%.  I don't know what's causing it but it could be the same issue you are having.  I posted a question (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41938459/sudden-drop-in-admob-show-rate) but no answer yet.

Comment: Are you sure it's a size issue?  What version of Android do you have on your S3?

Answer (score 0):

We'd figured this out through trial and error, but it appears that if AdMob determines there is not enough space available to display the entire ad, it will not return one, which would explain what you are experiencing on the smaller devices.